# C++ template deduction - T becomes a pointer type

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I have this code snipplet

```
template <typename T>
void p(const T* value)
{
  std::cout << *value << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void p(const T& value)
{
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int* i = new int(5);
  p(i);
}
```

1) According to https://cppinsights.io/ the template functions are equvilant to

```
template <typename T>
void p(const T* value)
{
  std::cout << *value << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void p(const T& value)
{
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:18 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void p<int *>(int *const & value)
{
  std::cout.operator<<(value).operator<<(std::endl);
}
#endif
```

For me this is strange. According to "Item 1 of Effective modern c++" the only case when a T can deduced as T& (or T* I guess) is when the function parameter is a universal reference (forwarding reference). However this case T is deduced as int*, but the parameter if just a pointer.

2)
If I replace

```
int* i = new int(5);
```

with

```
const int* i = new int(5);
```

This is the result
(what I expected for the first place)

```
template <typename T>
void p(const T* value)
{
  std::cout << *value << std::endl;
}

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:18 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void p<int>(const int * value)
{
  std::cout.operator<<(*value).operator<<(std::endl);
}
#endif


template <typename T>
void p(const T& value)
{
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

3)
Back to 1), if I remove the overload

```
template <typename T>
void p(const T& value)
```

So I have only

```
template <typename T>
void p(const T* value)
{
  std::cout << *value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int* i = new int(5);
  p(i);
}
```

The result is

```
template <typename T>
void p(const T* value)
{
  std::cout << *value << std::endl;
}

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:12 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void p<int>(const int * value)
{
  std::cout.operator<<(*value).operator<<(std::endl);
}
#endif


int main()
{
  int * i = new int{5};
  p(i);
}
```

Could you please explaint me why it is possible for T to be deduced as int* in question 1) int in question 2)?
Also I don't understand order of template argument deduction 3).

Thanks for any hints / explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit conversion sequence from `int *` to `int * const &` is better than the implicit conversion sequence from `int *` to `const int *`.

The latter contains a [qualification conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), and the former doesn't.

Template argument deduction is answering the question "what type do I substitute `T` for", not "what is the type of `value`". For `template <typename T> void p(const T* value)` that *must* strip a `*` off the argument's type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, the compiler picked the reference overload, because that one does not contain a constness conversion, while the other does. I changed the overload with the pointer to `template <typename T>
void p( T*  value)`, and now (there is no const conversion) the compiler choose this one instead.For the last paragraph of your answer, I will have to reread it and rethink it again.